Impedance matching using Balun
community, your help and guidance is needed!
I want to design an impedance matching circuit in Altium Designer using the following diagram.
Here are the details of my design:

The left side is connected is to be connected with solder pads, and it must have an impedance of 100 ohms.

In the middle is Balun transformer: TC2-72T+ with 1:2 (impedance ratio) CORE & WIRE Transformer, 10 - 700 MHz, 50 Ω.

On the right side is (BKL 0409074 SMA panel jack, 50 ohms) and it must be connected with an impedance matching of 50 ohms.


I have the footprints of transformer and SMA plug in Altium. Can you help me with connections in Altium and how can I achieve this? Your help will be highly appreciated.
Thank you.


Do you have the details of the PCB stackup (number of layers, copper thickness, layer spacing, dielectric constants)? You can find calculators for microstrip and stripline structures on Alium's web site.  The links in the article will take you instructions on how to do this in Altium.


In middle is Balun transformer: TC2-72T+ with 1:2 CORE & WIRE
Transformer, 10 - 700 MHz, 50Ω.

If you want to transform 100 Ω to 50 Ω using a transformer, you need a ratio of \$2:\sqrt2\$ or vice versa. You say your transformer turns ratio is 1:2 and, that could transform 100 Ω to 400 Ω or, operated in reverse would transform 100 Ω to 25 Ω.
Hence, your turns ratio needs to be \$2:\sqrt2\$ or vice versa if operated in reverse. The lower number of turns is connected to the lower impedance.
If you want to know why a 2:1 transformer doesn't work consider the secondary voltage and current. The secondary voltage will be half the primary voltage and, secondary current will be twice the primary current. That leads to an impedance reduction (using ohm's law) of 4:1.

Mini-Circuits gives the impedance ratio, not turns ratio.

Sorry my mistake. Thanks for the info!
